# JMS Connectionfactory gives NullPointerException in TomEE+ 1.5.1 Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jms, code-injection

I'm testing out TomEE+ because it wraps a lot of features I need in a new system. Apache ActiveMQ being one of them. But I have some difficulties getting the JMS to work, and my efforts to find a solution havent yielded any results. I even tried to google for an answer!

Even when I try the "out-of-the-box" example:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

public class MyServet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name = "foo")
    private Topic fooTopic;

    @Resource(name = "bar")
    private Queue barQueue;

    @Resource
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //...

        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        // Create a Session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(fooTopic);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

        // Create a message
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello World!");

        // Tell the producer to send the message
        producer.send(message);

        //...
    }

}
```

I get the same problems, my ConnectionFactory is null. When I debug I can see that this is the case with all my @Resource annotated members. I would think that my members would be instanciated through injection when correctly annotated?

I tried to add this to my tomee.xml, with no result:

```
<Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
  BrokerXmlConfig =  broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)
  ServerUrl       =  tcp://localhost:61616
</Resource>

<Resource id="MyJmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
  ResourceAdapter = MyJmsResourceAdapter
</Resource>

<Container id="MyJmsMdbContainer" ctype="MESSAGE">
  ResourceAdapter = MyJmsResourceAdapter
</Container>

<Resource id="bar" type="javax.jms.Queue"/>
<Resource id="foo" type="javax.jms.Topic"/>
```

Still I get a NullPointerException when I run the example. Any suggestions as to where I might be missing something. Besides the addition to the tomee.xml I am running the 1.5.1 version of TomEE+ with nothing changed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the connection factory resource code to following. It should work

```
@Resource(name = "MyJMSConnectionFactory", type = ConnectionFactory.class)
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Comment: Hi. I only just saw your answer. I did solve it by reinstalling a fresh TomEE+ installation, and then it worked with the out of the box solution a seen here: http://activemq.apache.org/tomee.html But I have also seen your answer mentioned.